# latest version of redshift with crazy compile times

Tags: amazon-web-services, time, compilation, amazon-redshift

We have been using redshift for months with Compilation times of 10s in some queries (this IS normal).  Suddenly our clients in US regions have started to have compile times of 5 minutes!!.  But this week, our other customers in European regions who were working ok have started experiencing the same problem.  5m compilation times!!.  Has it happened to anyone else?

We Think that the problema is in aws.

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws or contact AWS Support.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.